# Is it safe to install VirtualBox for 10.10 in 11.04?

Tags: 10.10, 11.04, virtualbox

Is it safe to install virtual box (for maverick) on natty beta 2?

I would like have Windows in VirtualBox and I upgraded my maverick to unity. But VirtualBox has not released a version for natty yet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Maverick version works just fine in Natty (speaking as somebody who's currently doing a load of Photoshop work in an XP VM). If you upgrade from Maverick, it'll continue to work as before.

Whether it's *safe* or not, Natty still isn't a production-ready operating system. If you need it for work, you'd do best to hold out until after it's released (and even then, you might want to wait a couple of weeks).

Comment: thanx :) i wanted vb for exactly the same reason. photoshop.